# Breathing at nostrils

Tags: breathing

I usually focus on breath at the stomach but recently decided to try at the nostrils as I read it's better and also that's what the Buddha taught. I have no problem feeling the breath going in as it feels cooler but 99% of the time I feel nothing breathing out. So i just try to focus my mind in that area even though there's no sensation bring felt. Is this ok or should I just stick to stomach?

Answer (score 1):

it's actually a step-up that you can feel the temperature of the breath. It indicates that your level of concentration is above-normal. I would suggest that you continue the breath practice consistently for a few weeks to a month (without expecting any results - I've learnt that 'letting things be' is the key when meditating.) You should be able to feel more at your nostrils by then. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you.  One thing I notice is that if I wear earplugs I can concentrate more

Comment: That was what I was advised at the meditation retreat I attended as well. No harm in using earplugs to block out noise / distraction, since our goal is to enable a higher level of concentration.

Answer (score 1):

The Buddha never taught about nostrils.

The Anapanasati Sutta instructs to bring mindfulness (recollection of/being established in Dhamma principles) to the fore.

The most important aspect of Anapanasati meditation is the mind is at ease so the mind remains clear & feels the breathing in a natural way.

If the breathing is prematurely & deliberately watched at the nostrils, eventually, the breathing will become undiscernible because the breathing becomes too fine but the ambitious mind remains too coarse. In addition, sleepiness/sloth will likely develop.

Stream-enterers do not attempt to direct the mind upon/towards the breathing. Instead, stream-enters (like silent predators) allow the breathing to come to the mind.